# How to handle object groups in blender game engine?

Tags: python, game-engine, blender

I know there's a way to find out the group in which the certain object is in BGE.
In the API it says that you use `KX_GameObject(SCA_IObject)` and `groupObject` to get the group the object is in and `groupMembers` to get a list of all objects in the group. I tried many diferent ways to get it working, but I always get an error. Plese can someone tell me how to do it?

Here's a lonk to the API:
http://blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_73a_release/bge.types.KX_GameObject.html?highlight=group#bge.types.KX_GameObject.groupMembers

Here's the code.

```
import bge
from bge import logic
import bpy

cont = bge.logic.getCurrentController()
own = cont.owner
scene = logic.getCurrentScene()
objs = scene.objects

print(objs)


#here I tried to get the list of members in the group
group = bpy.data.groups["group"]
print(group.groupMembers)
#ERROR: 'Group' object has no attribute 'groupMembers'


#here I tried to get the group object is in
cube = bpy.data.objects["Cube"]
print(cube.groupObject)
#ERROR: 'Object' object has no attribute 'groupObject'
```

Thanks.

Comment: Could you ellaborate _how_ your program failed ? From the doc, you write `my_object.groupObject` to get _"the group object that the object belongs to or None if the object is not part of a group"_ Did this raised an exception ? Did you get `None` as you were expecting something ? Are you certain that the object belongs to a group ? May I suggest you to write a [minimal program](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) demonstrating you issue ?

Comment: `group`is probably (maybe?) not a `KX_GameObject` instance. Try to inspect more closely your `group` (resp `cube`) object by adding something like `print(type(group))`, `print(group)`, `print(group.__dict__)`.

Comment: Truest me... I tryed for an hour before asking it on stack overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.groupMembers is only for objects that are a added instance of a group

[image]

so a object may have no group members if it was not a group instance object or group instance subobject.

like added = own.scene.addObject('GroupInstance',own,0)

added = a empty

added.groupMembers = all the objects added with that empty

Comment: Sorry for the late response. Since I had posted this question, i have found out, that bpy does not work in the blender game engine. So this could never work but your alternative is a valid option.